# Passing data between interface override function to a method in service class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, foreground-service

i am having interface's override function that passes data of on click event from recycler view. i want to send this data from override function to a method in the same foreground service class. How do i do that?
whenever the recycler view item is clicked the data should change

here is my code in foreground service class

```
class KmService:Service(),TrackBinderClickItems{
    var songs:ArrayList<PlayListDatas> = ArrayList()
    private var kmBinder = KmBinder()
    var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
    private lateinit var mediaSession:MediaSessionCompat

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(baseContext,"My Music")
        return kmBinder
    }
    inner class KmBinder:Binder(){

        fun kmCurrentService(): KmService {
            return this@KmService
        }
    }
    fun showKmNotification(){
        var title = songTitle()

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(baseContext,MyAppContext.CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentText(title)
            .setContentText("artist")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.baseline_play_arrow_24)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,R.drawable.ilayaraja))
            .setStyle(androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle().setMediaSession(mediaSession.sessionToken))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .addAction(R.drawable.previoussong,"Previous",null)
            .addAction(R.drawable.baseline_play_arrow_24,"Play",null)
            .addAction(R.drawable.nextsong,"Next",null)
            .addAction(R.drawable.baseline_close_24,"Exit",null)
            .build()
        startForeground(13,notification)
    }


    private fun songTitle(songTitle:String = ""): String {
        return songTitle
    }

    override fun getTrackDetails(view: View, trackList: PlayListDatas) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked itemview ${trackList.song_title}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        songTitle(trackList.song_title)
    }

}
```